# How do developers manage to code a single file constantly being pushed and pulled on git?

Tags: git

For example, I'm wondering how developers work on a single file together, without stepping and tripping all over each other. Is it possible to code a single file at the same time as someone else (without them sitting in a chair next to you at the same computer, of course)? If so, how do they not mess up? (For example, imagine I make a change in the same place the someone else makes a change, at the same time, and then we push different changes to git).

So the end-all question is this: is it possible for multiple people to work on the same source file simultaneously? If so, how?

This may not be the perfect specific-type question for stack overflow, but I'm giving it a shot.

Comment: Git uses a merging strategy (in contrast to a locking strategy). The Emacs manual [has a pretty decent quick introduction to the differences between these approaches](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VCS-Merging.html).

Comment: The answer is how much of the file changes and how much stays the same. Typically when changes are made to a file 98% of the file remains unchanged. So unless the 2% that changes conflicts with the 2% that changed for another dev there is no conflict. Statistics ... it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only use git productively, but I will try to answer your question as generally as possible:

Almost all sourcecode management systems maintain some sort of "history". This history is a sequential collection of all commits that have been made to a repository. A commit always has an ID and the core-delta that it represents. A commit is always just a delta, never a snapshot of the whole repository. You can imagine the history like a one-dimensions write-only-stack. You can only ever put commits (changes) on top of it, but never remove one, nor put two things aside of each other. Everyone who has a copy(clone) of a repository has its own local history.
In that means, a commit is always depending on another commit that has been done before it.
Note that the remote repository has a history as well. More an that later.

When you make a change in your local copy, you are essentially putting a new commit on top of your local history-stack (I believe that this is why git actually calls your local modifications the "HEAD" - because they are always "on top" of everything else).
The left stack is your local history, the right one is the history of the remote repository. A, B, C, D and E are old commits that you and the remote repository know about. Now let's say, that X is your new, local commit that you want to push to the remote repository:

```
        |   |              |   |
        | X |              |   |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote
```

If you now push that commit to your remote repository, you are actually pushing the ID's of all the commits in your local history, as well as the new commit that is on top of all the old changes. The server will now try to match all commits up to the point where you made the change (in git terms, is is said, that you and the server "diverged").

```
Change:

        |   |              |   |
        | X |              |   |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote

Push:

        |   |              |   |
        | X |   ------->   |   |
        | E |   ------->   | E |
        | D |   ------->   | D |
        | C |   ------->   | C |
        | B |   ------->   | B |
        | A |   ------->   | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote

Check:

        |   |              |   |
        | X |   new --->   |   |
        | E |   <- ok ->   | E |
        | D |   <- ok ->   | D |
        | C |   <- ok ->   | C |
        | B |   <- ok ->   | B |
        | A |   <- ok ->   | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote
```

If both histories match (up to the change on top of that), the server will accept your change and merge it. Your both histories will now be in sync again, you are no longer "diverged". Like so:

```
Merged:

        |   |              |   |
        | X |              | X |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote
```

Coming back to your question:

If two developers edit a local copy at the same time and one of them pushes his/her change, the remote repository will be updated. It will have one more commit than the copy that you have locally. This is not only limited to one file, but the whole repository.

If you now try to push your local commit after another developer has already pushed something else, your local history will be different from the one of the remote server. Using the above illustration again, I want to show you whan happenes on the server:

```
Developer A (push successful):

        |   |              |   |
        | X | -----------> |   |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote

Developer B (push error):

        |   |              |   |
        | Y | ---- ?? ---> | X |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote
```

The remote server will reject your submitted change because it cannot resolve the dependency of your commit. Your commit depends on commit "E", but you are trying to put it on top of a completely different commit "Y" (which probably completely destroyed everything in commit "E", who knows?)

In order to solve this kind of issue, developers have to make sure that they are properly "in sync" with the remote repository that they want to push to, before pushing a local commit.

In git you do this with `git fetch` to get the latest history updates from the remote repository and `git rebase` to put your local changes (your HEAD) ontop of the changes that have been made on the remote server. This action will actually change your local history to match the one of the remote repository:

```
Before:

        |   |              |   |
        |   |              | G |
        | Y |              | F |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote

After fetch + rebase:

        | Y |              |   |
        | G | <----------- | G |
        | F | <----------- | F |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote

Push successful:

        | Y | -----------> |   |
        | G |              | G |
        | F |              | F |
        | E |              | E |
        | D |              | D |
        | C |              | C |
        | B |              | B |
        | A |              | A |
        -----              -----
         You              Remote
```

You can now push your local changes without problems.

Note that the process of rebasing is not always automatic. If your local history and the remote history "conflict" (in git that is editing the same lines in the same file), you will have to manually "resolve" the conflict before the rebase can succeed. This means that you, the developer B, have to manually choose, which one is the correct change to use.

For your question this means, that two developers can of course edit the same file simultaneously. But when they want to push their changes into a central repository, the latter one will have to resolve possible "conflicts" of his code with the previous committer.

I hope that this small explanation will help you.

Please be gentle, this is my first post on stackoverflow =)